# Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined

Tags: errors, wp-config, revisions

I made a local clone of a website that's running LIVE in order to safely work offline for a while. On every page of the local version I get a HUGE warning which says

**Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\local-tutorials\wp-config.php on line 95**

I guess it's been defined twice, once in `wp-config.php` and once elsewhere, right? However, I've no clue where it's been defined for the second time.

I searched `wp-config.php` for a second instance but no luck. I then checked the `functions.php` in my theme but it doesn't contain any statement on revisions.

[Googling](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Notice%3A+Constant+WP_POST_REVISIONS+already+defined&oq=Notice%3A+Constant+WP_POST_REVISIONS+already+defined&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) leads mainly to rather old threads that seem to address a different issue.

I believe the error is related to a reasonably recent (< 1 year?) Wordpress update since it didn't occur previously but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**

After searching all files, three contained `wp_post_revisions`:

- C:\xampp\htdocs\local-tutorials\wp-config.php
- C:\xampp\htdocs\local-tutorials\wp-includes\default-constants.php
- C:\xampp\htdocs\local-tutorials\wp-includes\revision.php

I commented out the `wp_post_revisions` in `default-constants.php` and this seems to solve the problem. I find that a bit awkward since `wp-config.php` is (partly) meant to override default constants.

So I think it's strange I get this huge error when I do so. Or am I missing something?

Comment: do a search on all your files instead of trying to guess where it is

Comment: I'm guessing that you're defining the constant in wp-config.php *after* WordPress has been loaded. Make sure that the `define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', ...` line is before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem before. 
I put `WP_POST_REVISIONS` in the end of `wp-config.php` file and it didn't work correctly. 
You should put your codes before defining `ABSPATH` and before this line:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

it must be something like in the following:

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 6 );
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

I hope it solves your problem. 
So don't put your codes in the end of `wp-config.php` file

Answer (score 1):

I have experience of same error like that:

```
Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in var/www/html/wp-config.php on 
line 95
```

And accordance code on line 95 is like following:

```
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

I make this 'false' and then move to line 86 above that commit:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

And then it works.
Hope your luck~