# Notice: Constant already defined in wp-config.php on (non-existent) line?

Tags: php, errors, wp-config

I've been tasked to move a website into a new domain, and I've encontered this weird issue.
On the homepage, I always see these:

> Notice: Constant AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL already defined in /home/gturnat/public_html/wp-config.php on line 99
>
> Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined in /home/gturnat/public_html/wp-config.php on line 100

---

What I have tried:

- [Notice: Constant WP_POST_REVISIONS already defined](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/158075/89236) suggests commenting the constants on `default-constants.php`, but it doesn't work.
- Settings `display_errors` to `0`, `'0'` or `'Off'` does nothing.
- Running `error_reporting(0)` will still display the errors.
- Creating a `mu-plugin` ([As suggested on How can I stop PHP notices from appearing in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997023)).
  Nothing happens and the plugin isn't even loaded.
  The errors still keep showing up.
- Tried to comment out the lines in `wp-config.php`, but didn't work. The notices are still there.
- Removed the lines **entirelly** and moved them around `wp-config.php`, but the warnings insist it is on line 99 and 100.
  Causing a syntax error inside  `wp-config.php` does lead to an error being logged, which means that the file isn't cached.
- Tried to enable and disable the debug mode, set `display_errors` to `false`, `0`, `'0'` and `'Off'`, but doesn't work.
- Ran `grep -1R WP_POST_REVISIONS *` and `grep -1R AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL *` with the following result:

  > root@webtest:# grep -lR WP_POST_REVISIONS *
  >   wp-config.php
  >   wp-includes/default-constants.php
  >   wp-includes/revision.php
  >   root@webtest:# grep -lR AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL *
  >   wp-config.php
  >   wp-includes/script-loader.php
  >   wp-includes/default-constants.php
  >   wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php

I really am out of any other idea to try.

---

I'm using Wordpress 4.7.2, running on PHP 5.4 with the following modules loaded:

[image: loaded modules]

There is no op-cache working in the server. Just those options.

PHP was configured with the following options:

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/opt/alt/php54' '--exec-prefix=/opt/alt/php54' '--bindir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/alt/php54/etc' '--datadir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/alt/php54/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/alt/php54/link/conf' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-layout=GNU' '--disable-debug' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--without-gdbm' '--with-pic' '--with-zlib' '--with-bz2' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-openssl' '--with-kerberos' '--with-mhash' '--with-readline' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/alt/pcre/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/alt/libxml2/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/alt/curlssl/usr' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-xml' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--enable-dbx=shared,/usr' '--enable-dom=shared' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-intl=shared' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--enable-soap=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-sqlite3=shared,/opt/alt/sqlite/usr' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-t1lib=/opt/alt/t1lib/usr' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/opt/alt/sqlite/usr' '--with-mssql=shared,/opt/alt/freetds/usr' '--with-interbase=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-firebird=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/opt/alt/freetds/usr' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr' '--with-tidy=shared,/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr' '--with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-pspell=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--with-icu-dir=/opt/alt/libicu/usr' '--with-sybase-ct=shared,/opt/alt/freetds/usr'
```

---

As a testing point, I tried to run it on PHP 5.6, with the same results, with the following modules:

[image: php 5.6]

Comment: Maybe the error was there all the time in the prior server/domain -- but [the level of PHP error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-error-php-ini) is set differently now on the new server.  Sometimes you have to decide if you are going to fight it or bury it...at least to get the site running so you can continue to debug elsewhere.

Comment: @CC Honestly, I just want to bury it. I can dig through, but I have no idea where to dig.

Comment: Do a `find in files` in the entire directory for `AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL`, obviously something else is defining it. Also, comment out an essential constant like `DB_NAME`, see if the site is still working. It's possible that you are modifying the wrong `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: @Fayaz Way ahead of you. The "find in files" was already done (last point in the list) and I even ran `find ./ | grep wp-config` and there's only 2. The other one is the sample. I've even traced the files, from the `index.php` to the `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Clear your (Comet) Cache!

---

**Long answer:**

I only have 2 words: **Comet Cache**!

Comet Cache was enabled.
Checking the source code showed me a note like this, after the closing  `</html>`:

```
<!-- *´¨)
     ¸.•´¸.•*´¨) ¸.•*¨)
     (¸.•´ (¸.•` ¤ Comet Cache Notes ¤ ´¨) -->

<!-- Cache File Version Salt:       n/a -->

<!-- Cache File URL:                http://<my-domain> -->
<!-- Cache File Path:               /cache/comet-cache/cache/http/<my-domain>/index.html -->

<!-- Cache File Generated Via:      HTTP request -->
<!-- Cache File Generated On:       Feb 22nd, 2017 @ 5:37 pm UTC -->
<!-- Cache File Generated In:       4.59149 seconds -->

<!-- Cache File Expires On:         Mar 1st, 2017 @ 5:37 pm UTC -->
<!-- Cache File Auto-Rebuild On:    Mar 1st, 2017 @ 5:37 pm UTC -->

<!-- *´¨)
     ¸.•´¸.•*´¨) ¸.•*¨)
     (¸.•´ (¸.•` ¤ Comet Cache is Fully Functional ¤ ´¨) -->

<!-- Loaded via Cache On:    Feb 22nd, 2017 @ 5:37 pm UTC -->
<!-- Loaded via Cache In:    0.03472 seconds -->
```

Manually deleting `/cache/comet-cache/cache/http/<my-domain>/index.html` (path relative to your `/wp-content/` directory) solved the issue.

---

I feel so stupid for assuming that there was no caching going on. [Always blame the cache!](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Ha ha, yeah, if something happens so strange that it's not explainable at all, 99 times out of 100, it's some sort of cache :)

Comment: @Fayaz Lesson learned. Only wasted around 9 hours with this :/ I really assumed there was no caching at all going on, since stuff changed sometimes... Oh, well, better luck for me next time.

Comment: lol didn't even think about cache

Comment: @MarkKaplun Me neither. I mean, I looked on PHP's side, but it was on Wordpress' side where the caching was :/

Comment: I hope you learned the lesson: Plugins should not handle caching, servers should ;) Better learn configuring a server for that task, then throwing an application on top. Bonus: You get more control plus _much_ more caching power as requests that are available in cache never hit your PHP FPM or FCGI application server.

Comment: @kaiser You're right. I should check an .htaccess example about it. I read a little but I'm not entirelly happy about implementing it myself, since I know next to nothing about Wordpress.

Comment: Caching has nothing to do with WordPress (and not with user-access like `.htaccess` does for the _Apache_ webserver) or your server.

Comment: Now I'm super confused...

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any plugin that manipulates those definitions, this is most likely cause by having the two constants defined below the line in the `config.php` that says

> /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

The relatively high line numbers support this idea.

Comment: They aren't. I tried that too. They are on line 90 and 91. But **somehow** the warning is on line 99 and 100.

Comment: then most likely you are not looking at the right `wp-config`

Comment: ... and my 4.7 mostly vanila `wp-config` end in line 89, so even 90 sounds wrong

Comment: You can see my file on http://pastebin.com/HZhENpMu (in my defense, I didn't knew it is 100 lines long.). The lines 90 and 91 are commented, as you can see.

Comment: that looks good, which brings back the options that this is not the correct file to look at. Are you sure there isn't for example a `wp-config` in the directory above? One simple way to verify is to add a `die` or introduce a syntax error at the file you are looking at now

Comment: I tried that already. That's the 6th point. It does lead to a white page when writting random stuff inside the file.

Comment: Just to clean out my insality a bit, I edited the 3rd line to be `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');die(WP_MEMORY_LIMIT);`, and it showed `512M` as expected.