# Constant WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT already defined in /htdocs/wp-config.php

Tags: errors, wp-cron

I got this PHP error :

> Notice: Constant `WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT` already defined in /htdocs/wp-config.php on line 195

I don't understand because when I do a search in the wordpress project with the word `WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT` I got just this result :

[image]

How PHP can say *`WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT` is already defined* if the second code line in `default-constants.php` is wrapped by a condition like this :

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT' ) )
    define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 60);  // In seconds
```

Notice : *I did a google search and a load of web sites appeared with this error in the description so it's a common error.*

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin? Possibly helpful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257489/notice-constant-xyz-already-defined-in-wp-config-php-on-a-line-that-doesnt-exi

Comment: I did not find a plugin about cache. Is there a cache system in wordpress by default ?

Comment: There is no core provided file caching plugin in WP, so perhaps you are having a different issue.

Comment: Can we see line 195 of `wp-config.php`? Have you added stuff after the bit that says no editing past this point where it loads `wp-settings.php`?

Comment: @TomJNowell this was my mistake. Moving them above the That's All resolved the notice :)

Comment: @Jarmerson can you write the answer as an answer so people with the same problem can find it easily? Comments are easy to overlook

Comment: @TomJNowell will do :D

Answer (score 1):

Configurations in wp-config.php should be placed above the comment near the bottom that reads: **That's all, stop editing! Happy Publishing.**

Per [Editing wp-config.php](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/)

> The contents of the wp-config-sample.php file are in a very specific order. The order matters. If you already have a wp-config.php file, rearranging the contents of the file may create errors on your blog.

### Here are those lines near the bottom:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

### I've added my own configuration above those lines:

```
define( 'WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 120   ); 
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL',    300   );
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS',    5     );
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS',     7     );
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE',  true  );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

Add your configuration accordingly and those notices should resolve.

Comment: I added your configuration but it didn't fix the problem, do you have an other solution ? Thankssssss

Comment: @Céline this isn't a copy paste solution, this is just an example based on Jarods config file